# Does wso2esb support memcached and redis cache..?

Tags: redis, wso2, memcached, apache-axis, wso2-esb

Want to know wso2esb 4.9.0 support Memcache or Redis cache or not ,Can we use one of this cache tool to cache the response of the services in wso2esb.

If yes is there any documentation how to integrated esb with one of this cache tool.

Thank you..